# Conditionally counting number of ocurrences in a dataframe - performance improvement

Tags: r

I need to detect (among other things) the first occurrence of a non-"F" code in a patient's list, after the first "F" code occurrence. The below code seems to succeed in this, however it is shown to be too inefficient on the server running in  a data set of one million observations.

The final data set should have a variable of number of non-F codes (nhosp), and the first non-F code found after the first F-code appearance on the DAIGNOSTICO variable. No duplicates of ID.

- How can I improve both in terms of complexity and speed? Tidyverse pipe preferred.

This is how the result should look like:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 6
# Groups:   ID [7]
      ID DAIGNOSTICO data_entrada data_saida nhosp ficd
   <dbl> <chr>       <date>       <date>     <dbl> <chr>
1   1555 F180        1930-04-05   2005-03-15     1 T124
2   1234 F100        1980-04-01   2005-03-02     2 O155
3  16666 F120        1990-06-05   2005-03-18     0 <NA>
4 123456 F145        2001-03-07   2005-03-11     2 T123
5 177778 F155        2001-04-13   2005-03-22     2 G123
6 166666 F125        2002-03-12   2005-03-19     2 W345
7  12345 F150        2002-06-03   2005-03-07     4 K709
```

This is how my code looks like currently:

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

simulation <- read_csv("SIMULADO.txt",  col_types = cols(
    data_entrada = col_date("%d/%m/%Y"),
    data_saida = col_date("%d/%m/%Y")
  )
)

simulation <- as.data.frame(simulation)

simulation[, "nhosp"] <- 0
oldpos <- 1

for (i in 1:nrow(simulation)) {
  if (grepl("F", simulation[i, "DAIGNOSTICO"], )) { # Has F?
    oldpos <- i
    clin <- 0
    simulation[i, "hasF"] <- T
  } else {
    simulation[i, "hasF"] <-F
  }
  if (simulation[i, "ID"] == simulation[oldpos, "ID"]) { # same person?
    if (simulation[oldpos, "hasF"] == T) { # Did she/him had F?
      simulation[i, "hasF"] <- T
      if (simulation[i, "data_entrada"] > simulation[oldpos, "data_entrada"]) { # é subsequente?
        if (!grepl("F", simulation[i, "DAIGNOSTICO"], )) { # not-F?
          simulation[i,"hasC"] <- T
          clin <- 1
          simulation[i, "ficd"] <- simulation[i, "DAIGNOSTICO"]
          simulation[i, "nhosp"] <- clin 
          first_cc <- simulation[i, "DAIGNOSTICO"]
      }
    }
    }
  }
}

dt1 <- simulation %>%
  arrange(data_entrada) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  select(ficd) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  slice(1)

dt2 <- simulation %>%
  arrange(data_entrada) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(hasF == T) %>%
  mutate(nhosp = cumsum(nhosp),
         nhosp = max(nhosp)) %>%
  select(-ficd,-hasF, -hasC) %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  full_join(dt1, by = "ID")

dt2
```

And this is an example data set, with some errors to check robustness of the code:

```
ID,   DAIGNOSTICO, data_entrada,    data_saida
123490, O100,   01/04/1980, 02/03/2005
123490, O100,   01/04/1981, 02/03/2005
123491, O101,   01/04/1980, 02/03/2005
123491, O101,   01/04/1981, 02/03/2005
1234,   F100,   01/04/1980, 02/03/2005
1234,   O155,   02/04/1980, 03/03/2005
1234,   G123,   05/05/1982, 04/03/2005
12345,  T124,   01/06/2002, 05/03/2005
12345,  Y124,   02/06/2002, 06/03/2005
12345,  F150,   03/06/2002, 07/03/2005
12345,  K709,   04/06/2002, 08/03/2005
12345,  Y709,   05/06/2002, 09/03/2005
12345,  F150,   03/06/2002, 07/03/2005
12345,  K710,   06/06/2002, 08/03/2005
12345,  K711,   07/06/2002, 10/03/2005
12345,  F150,   08/06/2002, 07/03/2005
123456, F145,   07/03/2001, 11/03/2005
123456, T123,   08/03/2001, 12/03/2005
123456, P123,   09/03/2001, 13/03/2005
1555    ,R155,  04/04/1930, 14/03/2005
1555    ,F180,  05/04/1930, 15/03/2005
1555    ,T124,  06/04/1930, 16/03/2005
1555    ,F708,  07/04/1930, 17/03/2005
16666   ,F120,  05/06/1990, 18/03/2005
166666, F125,   12/03/2002, 19/03/2005
166666, W345,   13/03/2002, 20/03/2005
166666, L123,   14/03/2002, 21/03/2005
177778, F155,   13/04/2001, 22/03/2005
177778, G123,   14/04/2001, 23/03/2005
177778, F190,   15/04/2001, 24/03/2005
177778, E124,   16/04/2001, 25/03/2005
177779, G155,   13/04/2001, 22/03/2005
177779, G123,   14/04/2001, 23/03/2005
177779, G190,   15/04/2001, 24/03/2005
177779, E124,   16/04/2001, 25/03/2005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(str_detect(DAIGNOSTICO, "^F")) > 0) %>% 
  mutate(nhosp = sum(str_detect(DAIGNOSTICO, "^[^F]")),
         ficd  = lead(DAIGNOSTICO)) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(DAIGNOSTICO, "^F")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 6
      ID DAIGNOSTICO data_entrada data_saida nhosp ficd 
   <dbl> <chr>       <chr>        <chr>      <int> <chr>
1   1234 F100        01/04/1980   02/03/2005     2 O155 
2   1555 F180        05/04/1930   15/03/2005     1 T124 
3  12345 F150        03/06/2002   07/03/2005     4 K709 
4  16666 F120        05/06/1990   18/03/2005     0 NA   
5 123456 F145        07/03/2001   11/03/2005     2 T123 
6 166666 F125        12/03/2002   19/03/2005     2 W345 
7 177778 F155        13/04/2001   22/03/2005     2 G123
```

### Edit

I think there might be a flaw, perhaps

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(
    cumsum(str_detect(DAIGNOSTICO, "^F")) == 1 | 
      !str_detect(DAIGNOSTICO, "^F") & cumsum(str_detect(DAIGNOSTICO, "^F")) > 0
    ) %>% 
  mutate(nhosp = sum(str_detect(DAIGNOSTICO, "^[^F]")),
         ficd  = lead(DAIGNOSTICO)) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(DAIGNOSTICO, "^F")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

is a better solution.